# Current Joda Time performance on Android?

Tags: android, jodatime

I've heard performance concerns **in the past** about using Joda Time on Android. One specific example was an issue with the way that timezone data was loaded, which was causing a considerable amount of memory to remain allocated when it was no longer needed, for the life of the application. However, I believe some of those issues have also been addressed by this point.

Aside from general "I don't trust it" sentiment, :) are there any **current** issues that continue make Joda Time a poor choice for dealing with dates on Android?

Comment: There is an [Android port](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) of JodaTime. Don't know if it is really necessary, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem still exists. The issue was the library's usage of `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`. This issue has NOT been fixed as of Android `6.0.1_r11` - see [here](http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/04/06/slow-ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream.html#appendix-how-we-pinpointed-the-slow-operations-in-getresourceasstream) for details.

As of this writing, the default `ZoneInfoProvider` [still uses this mechanism](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/836aa412608fea64a9bd66a403637dda15dcb161/src/main/java/org/joda/time/tz/ZoneInfoProvider.java#L204) - from the the current tip of `master`:

```
private InputStream openResource(String name) throws IOException {
    InputStream in;
    if (iFileDir != null) {
        in = new FileInputStream(new File(iFileDir, name));
    } else {
        final String path = iResourcePath.concat(name);
        in = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<InputStream>() {
            public InputStream run() {
                if (iLoader != null) {
                    return iLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
                } else {
                    return ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(path);
                }
            }
        });
        if (in == null) {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(40)
                .append("Resource not found: \"")
                .append(path)
                .append("\" ClassLoader: ")
                .append(iLoader != null ? iLoader.toString() : "system");
            throw new IOException(buf.toString());
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

In a few jumps, you can trace the usage of this problem method back to `DateTimeZone.getProvider` [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/836aa412608fea64a9bd66a403637dda15dcb161/src/main/java/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.java#L413):

```
public static Provider getProvider() {
    Provider provider = cProvider.get();
    if (provider == null) {
        provider = getDefaultProvider();
        if (!cProvider.compareAndSet(null, provider)) {
            provider = cProvider.get();
        }
    }
    return provider;
}
```

`getDefaultProvider()`  will create the problematic `ZoneInfoProvider` class; so, if you use JodaTime with the default `Provider`, you will still have the same performance issues.